# Why Dashboard shows incorrect checklist URL

Tags: error, civicrm-home, civicrm.settings.php, urls, resource-urls

There is an incorrect checklist URL on our CiviCRM Home Dashboard under "Configure and Extend".

The correct URL is available at Administer -> Administration Console -> Configuration Checklist.

Any idea why? Is there a config setting somewhere that is set incorrectly that might cause this?  I did not initially set up this site but am trying to fix any possible issues.

- Correct URL contains:
  wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fconfigtask&reset=1
- Incorrect URL contains:
  civi/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/configtask&reset=1

Thanks,
Michele